# Blender video doesn't render

Tags: rendering, video

can't seem to make this one work. File link:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_TpBTRuHY6-w6mH_UPhAcQOg5tArTFnC

I have no idea why.
Please can you help?
Thanks
NewToBlenderGirl

Comment: Welcome to [blender.se].  Please read [ask] and [tour].  Questions are moderated, so please edit your question to avoid disappointment.  You can also [upload your file direct to question](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: Sorry folks, turns out I was rendering a photo instead. Works now.